# Angular 2 - Why do I need zone.run()?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to create a component in Angular 2 which displays data from a service. The service basically loads some data from a json file after some input from the user. I've been trying to get the component to update but it does not seem to recognize changes unless I call zone.run() after submitting an event from from my service. My code is as follows for the component...

```
@Component({
    selector: 'assess-asset-group',
    directives: [AssetComponent, AssetHeaderComponent, NgFor, NgIf],
    template: `

            <div *ngIf="assetService.schema != null">
                <div class="asset-group" *ngFor="#assetTypeName of assetService.schema.assetTypeNames"> 
                    <div class="asset-type-title"><span>{{assetService.schema.assetTypes[assetTypeName].name}}s</span></div> 
                    <table class="asset-group-table" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                        <thead>
                            <tr assess-asset-header [assetType]="assetService.schema.assetTypes[assetTypeName]"></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr assess-asset *ngFor="#asset of assetService.assetsForType(assetTypeName)" [asset]="asset"></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button class="new-asset-btn" (click)="assetService.addAsset(assetTypeName)">New</button>
                </div>
            </div>`,
    providers: [provide(AssetService, {useValue: injector.get(AssetService)})]
})
export class AssetGroupComponent {

    public assetService: AssetService;
    public zone: NgZone;

    constructor( @Inject(AssetService) assetService: AssetService, zone: NgZone) {
        this.assetService = assetService;
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.assetService.proejectLoadedEmitter.subscribe((e) => { this.zone.run(() => { }) });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.assetService.proejectLoadedEmitter.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this what I need to do in order to update the view?

UPDATE - AssetService Class

```
@Injectable()
export class AssetService{
    public assets: Assets.Asset[] = [];
    public assetTypeDefinitions: any = null;

    public schema: Schema = null;
    public assetsAsObj: any = null; // Asset file loaded as object

    @Output() proejectLoadedEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(){
    }

    public loadProject(config: Project){
        // Load schema
        // populate AssetTypeDefinitions as object keyed by type
        let data = fs.readFileSync(config.schemaPath, 'utf8');
        if (!data) {
            utils.logError("Error reading schema file");
            return;
        }
        let struc = fs.readFileSync(config.structurePath, 'utf8');
        if (!struc) {
            utils.logError("Error reading structure file");
            return;
        }

        this.schema = new Schema(JSON.parse(data), struc);
        this.readAssets(config.assetFilePath);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Adds a new asset to the assets array 
     * @details Constructs the asset based on the type and populates
     *  its fields with appropreiate default values
     * 
     * @param type The type of the asset - specified in the schema
     */
    public addAsset(type: string): void {
        // Need to make sure there is a loaded type definition for the specified type
        if(!this.schema.assetTypes.hasOwnProperty(type)){
            utils.logError("Error occured during call to addAsset - type \"" + type + "\" is not specified in the loaded schema");
            return;
        }
        // Creeate a new asset object - passing in the type definition from the schema
        this.assets.push(new Assets.Asset(this.schema.assetTypes[type]));
    }   

    /**
     * Write the current assets to a file using the specified format
     * If the outputPasth isn't specied try and load it from the project.json file
     */
    public writeAssets(format:AssetWriteFormat, outputPath?: string) : void {

        var outStructureStr = this.schema.structureStr;
        // insert AS properties from schema into output assets
        this.schema.properties.forEach(prop => {
            outStructureStr = outStructureStr.replace(new RegExp('"' + prop +'"', 'i'), this.retriveValueForSchemaProperty(prop));
        });

        fs.writeFileSync("C:/Projects/Assess/assets.json", outStructureStr);
    }

    public readAssets(inputPath?: string) : void{
        let assetsStr = fs.readFileSync(inputPath, 'utf8');

        let strucToAssetMap = {};
        let strucObj = JSON.parse(this.schema.structureStr);
        this.schema.properties.forEach(p => {
            strucToAssetMap[p] = this.findValueInObject(strucObj, p).reverse();
        });

        // @TODO Load custom properties
        let assetsObj = JSON.parse(assetsStr);
        var c = null;
        strucToAssetMap["AS_ASSETS"].forEach(p => {
            if(c == null){
                c = assetsObj[p];
            }else{
                c = c[p];
            }
        });
        c.forEach((asset) => {
            let a:Assets.Asset = new Assets.Asset(this.schema.assetTypes[asset.type], asset);
            this.assets.push(a);
        });
        console.log(this.assets);
        this.proejectLoadedEmitter.emit(null);
    }

    public assetsForType(type:string): Assets.Asset[]{
        var ret: Assets.Asset[] = [];
        for(let idx in this.assets){
            if(this.assets[idx].definition.type === type){
                ret.push(this.assets[idx]);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public retriveValueForSchemaProperty(property: string) : string{
        if(AS_SchemaTypes.indexOf(property) != -1){
            switch (property) {
                case "AS_ASSETS":
                    let outAssets = [];
                    this.assets.forEach((asset) => {
                        let outAsset = {};
                        outAsset["type"] = asset.definition.type;

                        for (let key in asset.fields) {
                            outAsset[key] = asset.fields[key].value;
                        }
                        outAssets.push(outAsset);
                    });
                    return JSON.stringify(outAssets, null, "\t");
            }
        }else{
            // @TODO Retrive custom properties
            return '"DDDDDD"';
        }
        return "";
    }

    public findValueInObject(obj: any, property: string, path: any[] = []): any[] {
        for(let x in obj){;
            let val = obj[x];
            if (val == property){
                path.push(x);
                return path;
            }
            else if(val != null && typeof val == 'object'){
                let v = this.findValueInObject(val, property, path);
                if(v != null){
                    path.push(x);   
                    return path;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Angular uses zones for change detection, e.g. external libraries can cause code to leave Angulars zone and "break" change detection http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This would require knowledge about the inner workings of the `AssetService` you're using.

Angular runs the code of your components within its zone where most async APIs (`addEventListener`, `setTimeout`, ...) are patched so the zone can notify Angular when such an async callback has happend. This is when Angular runs change detection.

If you initialized `AssetService` outside Angular or `AssetService` by other means executes code outside Angulars zone, then Angular doesn't get notified about happened async callbacks and doesn't run change detection.

With `zone.run(...)` you explicitely make code execute inside Angulars zone and change detection is run afterwards.

Comment: My AssetService is created using Injector.resolveAndCreate, however the event triggering the loadProject call is happening from an Electron menu. I have updated my post to include the AssetService code. I assume that you are correct and it simply isn't being monitored by Angular due to how the class is set up. If this is the case have I taken the proper approach to solving the issue?

Comment: Sounds like this could be the cause. Just use `zone.run(...)` for code that is executed by the event handler.

Comment: What method of your service is called when the Electron event is fired?

Comment: I call `injector.get(AssetService).loadProject(ProjectService.currentProject);`

Comment: I don't know Electron. This code is not included in your question. What of your methods get called from Electron?

Comment: I think I got it. You can wrap `this.proejectLoadedEmitter.emit(null);` with `zone.run(...)`, then you don't need it on the subscriber of the emitted event.

Comment: `EventEmitter` shouldn't be used in services. `@Output()` in a service is also redundant. Use an `Observer` or `Subject` instead. `EventEmitter` should only be used for `@Output()` in component and directives.

Comment: How would I get access to zone inside the service? I had the same thought but can't seem to get NgZone to inject properly

Comment: If it is actually a service that is instantiated by Angular, then injecting the zone should work exactly like in the component.

Comment: It should be as I am using `var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
 AssetService
]);` to create it. When I try to add NgZone to the constructor of Asset Service I get `Uncaught No provider for NgZone! (AssetService -> NgZone)`

Comment: I see. You mentioned it in the first comment. No, this doesn't count. It's Angular code but the created injector is not instantiated by Angular. This code is outside of your Angular application I guess (before `bootstrap()`)?

Comment: I think I see the problem sort of. When the component injects AssetService  then NgZone is injected properly, however when I call `injector.get(AssetService).loadProject(ProjectService.currentProject);` outside the component then there is no provider for NgZone and thus it can't get the AssetService instance. I assumed that it should already be instantiated but perhaps not

Comment: That's exactly how it is. Angular has it's own injector. With `Injector.resolveAndCreate([ AssetService ]);` you create an independent injector that only has a single provider. Adding `NgZone` to this provider list also won't fix anything because it would inject a different zone. Only when Angulars injector instance creates the service instance you get the correct zone injected.

Comment: That makes sense, Is there an easy way to hook into that Injector or is it best to just switch to Observables/subscribers?

Comment: I don't know your situation. Where is this code `Injector.resolveAndCreate([ AssetService ]);`. You can inject the injector inside Angular. `bootstrap(...).then(appRef => appRef.injector)` also provides access to the injector. (see also http://plnkr.co/edit/SF8gsYN1SvmUbkosHjqQ?p=preview `main.ts`)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Which has better performance, running zone or individually calling detectChanges() in each component?

Comment: `detectChanges` is better because it only runs change detection for the component (with descendants), while `zone.run()` runs CD for the whole application.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So is it OK to say that if I 
 use the patched settimeout like : `setTimeout(()=>somethingThatRunsOutsideAngularZone(),1000)` , then I don't need ngzone ? since setTimeout already runs change detection?

Comment: Code that is invoked automatically runs inside Angulars zone and you shouldn't need to take care. If you pass callbacks to code that was for example initialized outside Angular or some API (like GeoLocation) that is not fully covered by NgZone, then you might need to explicitely use `zone.run(...)`, but that should be the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly caused by referencing assetService, the argument, and not this.assetService, in your views? Maybe that is causing Angular's change detection not to be triggered without calling zone.run().