# Angular 2 + OnPush: Change detection does not work on pouchdb callbacks

Tags: angular, pouchdb, angular2-changedetection

I am using Angular 2 in an ionic app in combination with PouchDB as database. For performance reasons I chose to use OnPush+Async pipe everywhere. I now stumbled upon the fact, that if a pouchdb event causes a change, it is not reflected in the template:

I have a database class that just counts the number of db changes:

```
@Injectable()
export class Database {
  foo$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  (...)

  sync(url, options) {
    this.pouchdb.sync(url, options)
      .on('change', this.changed.bind(this));
    this.foo$.subscribe(count => console.debug('the count is', count));
  }

  changed() {
    this.foo$.next(this.foo$.value + 1);
  }
}
```

and inside a template I use the async pipe to display the number:

```
{{ db.foo$|async }}
```

But this does not work: The number is stuck, even if there are database changes (the console output shows the number of database changes). If I click on something, however, the number suddenly jumps to the correct value.

I find this astonishing because I thought that the async pipe works by subscribing to an observable and once this observable emits something, the value inside the template is updated. Obviously, this does not work here, because I know the observable emitted something (as I can see from the console output), but the change is not reflected in the template.

Do you know what causes this behavior / how to change it?

**Additional info**

In order to be sure that it's the combination of pouchDB <> Angular that causes the trouble, I used this function instead

```
sync(url, options) {
  window.setInterval(this.changed.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

which causes the value inside the template to get updated correctly every second.

**EDIT**

I found out that this dummy code

```
window.setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
```

fixes the problem, as it probably triggers change detection every second. What I don't understand is, why doesn't the async pipe detect the change without it?

Comment: Seems to me there must be more to it. I'd remove ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush to make sure that this is indeed part of the problem. Have you confirmed this?

Comment: Gut feeling: You are looking at two instances of Database. The one used in the template is not the same as the one on which .sync is called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You were right, it's not OnPush that is responsible, the same happens with ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default. I'm completely sure, however, that there are not two different database instances. I noticed another thing: If I execute this dummy code, everything works fine: 

    window.setInterval(() => {}, 1000);

So as far as I understand, this seems to be indeed a problem of change detection, the setInterval triggers a change detection every second. But I don't know understand why the async pipe doesn't detect the change without it...

Comment: I'd consider it a bug if the async pipe doesn't invoke change detection. `setInverval()` is probably the same as `setTimeout()` or `ApplicationRef.tick()` which causes application wide change detection

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Code runs outside angular zone so changes aren't handled by angular until next change detection cycle.

Using chrome dev tools, put a breakpoint in invocation of changed. Notice if you see a difference in call stack between pouchdb invocation and setInterval. Specifically, setInterval may have some zone rigging surrounding invocation, while the pouchdb invocation doesn't. If so, you could:

- Look into order of initialization - [see this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148813/angular-2-why-do-i-need-zone-run) - or if pouchdb could be otherwise monkey patched to invoke promises inside angular zone.
- Inject `private zone: NgZone` in Database constructor and use `this.zone.run(() => this.foo$.next(this.foo$.value + 1));` inside changed() to guarantee you get into angular zone.

If all else fails, cave in and manually flag a change detection ([using ChangeDetectionRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html)). However, as this has to be done in the component(s) using db, it's an absolutely horrible abstraction leak.

Enjoy. Let us know what you find.

Comment: thank you, zone.run() works as a workaround. Once I've a little more time I'll look into the problem in detail and will let you know what I found out