# Angular 4 instance field changed in code but change is not getting reflected in template

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Problem I am facing is that change in instance variable in component class  doesn't get reflected in my template file unless I explicitly call `ref.detectChanges`

`signInWithGoogle` is a method in my auth service which I calling from component to signin with google

```
signInWithGoogle(): Observable<User> {
    const observable = Observable.fromPromise(
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
    ).concatMap(result => {
      const url = environment.apiEndpoint + '/rest-auth/social/google/';
      const request = { access_token: result.credential.accessToken };
      return this.login(url, request);
    });
    return observable;
  }

  private login(url, request): Observable<User> {
    return this.http
      .post<User>(
        url,
        request
      )
      .concatMap((user: User) => {
        localStorage.setItem(
          environment.constants.STORAGE_USER,
          JSON.stringify(user)
        );
        return Observable.of(user);
      });
  }
```

Following is relevant code snippet from my component:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
    request = new LoginRequest();

    googleSignIn($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        this.authService.signInWithGoogle().subscribe(
          (user: User) => {
            console.log('logged in');
          },
          err => {
            this.errorMessage = 'Problem while signing in with google';
          }
        );
      }
}
```

This is how I am using `errorMessage` from component file in my template

```
<ngb-alert *ngIf="errorMessage" [dismissible]="false" type="danger">
      {{errorMessage}}
</ngb-alert>
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148813/angular-2-why-do-i-need-zone-run

Answer (score 1):

Use an observable instead:

```
// in component
errorMessage$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

googleSignIn($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.authService.signInWithGoogle().subscribe(
      (user: User) => {
        console.log('logged in');
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage$.next('Problem while signing in with google');
      }
    );
  }
```

And use async pipe in your template:

```
<ngb-alert *ngIf="errorMessage$ | async as errorMessage" [dismissible]="false" type="danger">
    {{ errorMessage }}
</ngb-alert>
```

Comment: I have tried the solution although it's working, there is a weird bug,  I need to click somewhere on component before `errorMessage` appears i.e it doesn't appears itself

Comment: Have you tried putting some static text inside the `<ngb-alert>`, to find out if its problem with `errorMessage` local variable, or with the `errorMessage$` observable itself?

Comment: I think problem is with observable because I have tried putting fixed error message but it's also not showing